# SublimeLinter ignore missing semicolons

Tags: sublimetext3, jslint, sublimelinter

I'm using a non-semicolon based coding style in one of my node apps, but the problem is SublimeLinter is logging all the missing semicolons, and eventually stops with a "Too many errors" error, and stops linting the rest of the script.

I've tried adding an `ignore_match` object to both the default and user settings, but nothing works. I've also restarted after each time I've tried just to make sure.

I've even tried adding it to the `excludes` portion of the settings.

This is the resource I was using:
[Linter Settings](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/linter_settings.html#ignore-match)

Here is one of the errors I'm getting:

```
Z:\www\site\node\workers.js: line 162, col 2, Missing semicolon. (W033)
```

Here's my settings: From User.

```
{
    "user": {
        "debug": true,
        "delay": 0.25,
        "error_color": "D02000",
        "gutter_theme": "Packages/SublimeLinter/gutter-themes/Default/Default.gutter-theme",
        "gutter_theme_excludes": [],
        "ignore_match": [
            "Missing semicolon."
        ],
        "lint_mode": "background",
        "linters": {
            "annotations": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "errors": [
                    "FIXME"
                ],
                "excludes": ["Missing semicolon"],
                "warnings": [
                    "TODO",
                    "README"
                ]
            },
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": ["Missing semicolon"]
            },
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": []
            }
        },
        "mark_style": "outline",
        "no_column_highlights_line": false,
        "passive_warnings": false,
        "paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "python_paths": {
            "linux": [],
            "osx": [],
            "windows": []
        },
        "rc_search_limit": 3,
        "shell_timeout": 10,
        "show_errors_on_save": false,
        "show_marks_in_minimap": true,
        "syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "php": "html",
            "python django": "python"
        },
        "warning_color": "DDB700",
        "wrap_find": true
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added `ignore_match": ["Missing semicolon"]` to the jshint options. It became:

```
    "jshint": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "excludes": [],
        "ignore_match": ["Missing semicolon"]
    },
```

Comment: Someone answered then deleted the post, but it was correct.
See edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complete answer,

```
Full user settings json file:


{
    "user": {
        "linters": {
            "jshint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "ignore_match": [
                    ".*Missing.*",
                ]
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer:

Add `ignore_match": ["Missing semicolon"]` to jshint options.

```
"jshint": {
        "@disable": false,
        "args": [],
        "excludes": [],
        "ignore_match": ["Missing semicolon"]
    },
```

Comment: Where exactly to add it. to sublime-linter settings, or jshint settings? (I didn't found)?